# milliseconds in mysql

Tags: mysql

This page explains how to format milliseconds
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

but how do I get the actual millisecond value beyond just .00000?

I've tried these:

```
  select unix_timestamp()+0;
  select SYSDATE()+0;
  select date_format(now(), '%f');
  select now()+0;
```

but none of theme give me precise and accurate milliseconds

Comment: Why do you expect milliseconds to work in MySQL? They are not supported in storage, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fractional-seconds.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug from mysql http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8523

Comment: That's pretty much it. The MySQL time function and data types does not support miliseconds. MySQL only deals with seconds resolution

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the microsecond from a field, use %f,

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(DATE_COLUMN/1000,'%Y-%M-%d %H:%i:%s %f') from TABLE_NAME;

+-------------------------------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(CREATETIME/1000,'%Y-%M-%d %H:%i:%s %f') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-March-18 16:02:54 342000                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Source : [MYSQL DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)